# VHDL : how to transform a Binary number into a decimal number

Tags: vhdl

I am learning VHDL through a project and I would like to transform a binary number into a decimal number (also expressed in binary). I need to do so because I am printing the number in decimal and if I try to print it without converting it I obtain an hexadecimal number...

For example 
I have 0010 1010 1111 0001 (2AF1) and I want 0001 0000 1001 1001 0011 (10993)

I must precise that my binary number is on 32 bits

It must be very simple because I can't find the solution on the internet ...

EDIT : This code is working and transform a binary number into a decimal number expressed in binary (d'10 = b'0001 0000)

```
    signal val0 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal val1 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal val2 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal val_Mux : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

            val_MUX <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(val0)+1) when cpt50M_Comp = '1' else val0;


    val1(3 downto 0)<= val_MUX(3 downto 0);
    loopA:
        for i in 0 to 6 generate
            val1(4*i+7 downto 4*i+4) <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(val_MUX(4*i+7 downto 4*i+4))+1) when val1(4*i+3 downto 4*i) > "1001" 
                    else val_MUX(4*i+7 downto 4*i+4);
            val2(4*i+3 downto 4*i) <= "0000" when val1(4*i+3 downto 4*i) > "1001" 
                    else val1(4*i+3 downto 4*i); 

    end generate loopA;
    val2(31 downto 28)<= val1(31 downto 28);


    val0 <= (others => '0') when reset='1' else 
        val2 when rising_edge(clk50);
```

Comment: Let's see your code for printing `2AF1`

Comment: I must precise this part of the code is given by our professor

Comment: Is this for synthesis or simulation? In simulation I'd use `natural'image(my_natural)` and print the string that produces. Or `natural'image(to_integer(unsigned(my_std_logic_vector))` if you like choosing the worst possible type declarations so you can use more type conversions.

Comment: It is for synthesis

Comment: You don't actually ask a question while coming close in your title. Your code appears unrelated and doesn't demonstrate effort. Binary to ASCII can be done for signed magnitude binary values using binary to BCD conversion (e.g. double dabble), taking each BCD digit in sequence and adding x"30. Two's complement negative numbers would want to be converted to signed magnitude first, any sign prepended. It might be useful to remove leading zeros. Other than the binary size you're not being specific enough.

Comment: The title is too short to explain what i need... I can send you the whole code but you will need a lot of time to read it ^^
I'll add some code I tought about but is not working

Comment: Please use the stack overflow search or Google search to look up the suggested double-dabble algorithm. I think there are even vhdl examples around. Binary to BCD conversion is quite common.

Comment: Can you explain your edit? Is it an answer to your own question? If yes, please post as an answer, not an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to go through 2 others signal before assigning the one display and assign the counter with the one display as done below :

```
signal val0 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal val1 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal val2 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal val_Mux : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

        val_MUX <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(val0)+1) when cpt50M_Comp = '1' else val0;


val1(3 downto 0)<= val_MUX(3 downto 0);
loopA:
    for i in 0 to 6 generate
        val1(4*i+7 downto 4*i+4) <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(val_MUX(4*i+7 downto 4*i+4))+1) when val1(4*i+3 downto 4*i) > "1001" 
                else val_MUX(4*i+7 downto 4*i+4);
        val2(4*i+3 downto 4*i) <= "0000" when val1(4*i+3 downto 4*i) > "1001" 
                else val1(4*i+3 downto 4*i); 

end generate loopA;
val2(31 downto 28)<= val1(31 downto 28);


val0 <= (others => '0') when reset='1' else 
    val2 when rising_edge(clk50);
```